# Completing the gaps in SQL query

Tags: sql

Let's assume we have a table that has the following:

```
PlayerID     Number_of_Awards
```

Each playerID is distinct. No duplicates.

For each number of awards, I want to look at the player count.

```
select number_of_awards, count(playerid) as cnt from table group by number_of_awards
```

However, when I get the output

```
 number_of_awards     cnt

       2               10
       3               2
       4               3
       6               1
```

I have the above table. 1, 5 are missing because no player has won only one award or 5 awards.

I want to fill out that gap. I want the output to be

```
 number_of_awards     cnt

       1               0
       2               10
       3               2
       4               3
       5               0
       6               1
```

Is there a sql function that fill out such gap? How do we do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select A.val,coalesce(cnt,0) from
(
select 1 as val 
union 
select 2 
union 
select 3 union selecct 4 union select 5 union select 6
)A left join 
(select number_of_awards, count(playerid) as cnt from table group by number_of_awards)B
on A.val=B.number_of_awards
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is only possible once I know that the maximum value will be 6. What if I don't know the maximum value?

Comment: @user98235, yes this is a bit static type - if u need dynamic then it will be different as this values are not available in your table

Comment: Oh, well. I guess i'll just have to live with it. Thanks for the answer. Although it's not what I was looking for, I will accept it. At least I found out there's no easy way around with a built-in sql function.

Answer (score 1):

A common trick is to use a numbers table containing a 'reasonable' range of numbers.

For example,

```
create table Numbers (
    N int primary key clustered not null
);
insert into Numbers Values (1, 2, 3, ..., <A reasonable value>);
```

You can then join on this table.

```
select
    num.N
    , award_cnt.cnt
from
    Numbers as num
left join
    (
    select number_of_awards, count(playerid) as cnt from table group by number_of_awards
    ) as award_cnt
    on
        num.N = award_cnt.number_of_awards
order by
    num.N
```

Answer (score 1):

You want this for an aggregation, so the original table has the rows you need.  So, I'm thinking:

```
with naw as (
      select number_of_awards, count(playerid) as cnt
      from t
      group by number_of_awards
     ),
     n as (
      select n.n
      from (select row_number() over (order by playerid) as n
            from t
           ) n join
           (select max(number_of_awards) as maxn
            from naw
           ) maxn
           on n.n <= maxn
     )
select n.n, coalesce(cnt, 0) as cnt
from n left join
     naw
     on n.n = naw.number_of_awards
order by n.n;
```

There may be even simpler methods, depending on the database.  For instance, Postgres supports `generate_series()` which is convenient for this type of problem.